# how to require each object in an array to exactly match one of the defined types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create an array of objects that can be passed into a react component. I'd like to require each potential object (within the array argument) passed in to match *one* of the potential types provided. So far, the union is allowing any fields provided in any of the various interfaces to be valid in other interfaces, when in reality I'd prefer it be more restrictive. I've been going through the documentation scanning over unions and control flow. I'm not sure if this can be done, but it seems like ... perhaps it should be possible to accomplish in a dynamic way without having to be explicit?

```js
interface IAnimal {
  eat: () => void,
  name: string
}

interface IDog extends IAnimal {
 bark: () => void,
}

interface ICat extends IAnimal {
 meow: () => void,
}

type ValidAnimals = IDog | ICat
```

```
// it needs to be either only a dog, or only a cat.

<MyComponent pets=[
 {
   name: "Sparky",
   eat: () => {},
   bark: () => {}
 },
 {
   name: "Whiskers",
   eat: () => {},
   meow: () => {}
 },
 {
   name: "Kitty",
   eat: () => {},
   bark: () => {}  // this should be not allowed, does not exist on cats (casting doesn't resolve this)
   meow: () => {}
 },
]
/>
```

Is there a means to have typescript identify that the provided cat in this case does not *exactly* match any of the possible types (ICat / IDog) ?

Comment: Is this an array set up at compile time (hard coded)? Or is it built from user or API dats?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship it would be hardcoded

Comment: Object types in TS are open, not closed, and unions are inclusive, not exclusive.  If you want to emulate exclusive unions you can write a utility type like `ExclusifyUnion` in the answer to one of the questions linked above.  Doing that with `ICat | IDog` yields [this code](https://tsplay.dev/N9Y38N) which behaves how you'd like.

Comment: It's a shame someone closed your question, because there are a couple of things that are close to an answer that I would have said.

Comment: I've voted to reopen.

Comment: Check here for one way you could handle this https://medium.com/tableau-engineering-blog/really-advanced-typescript-types-c590eee59a12#c90d

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a union type to your pets will infer that it is a dog or cat.

- If you want an array of Cats or Dogs, you would explicitly set the type to Idog[] or Icat[]
- If you want an array with Cats or Dogs, use the union type `const pets: IDog | ICat`
- Assigning a type by inferring the first element of the array is an anti-pattern. You'd like to explicitly state the variable's valid options, not vice versa.

Yet, the line that will fail will be the second property on the "Kitty" object.

```
type ValidAnimals = IDog | ICat

const pets: ValidAnimals[] = [
  {
    name: "Sparky",
    eat: () => { },
    bark: () => { }
  },
  {
    name: "Whiskers",
    eat: () => { },
    meow: () => { }
  },
  {
    name: "Kitty",
    eat: () => { },
    bark: () => { }
    meow: () => { } // fails here
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

sure-

```js
interface IAnimal {
    eat: () => void;
    name: string;
}

interface IDog extends IAnimal {
    bark: () => void;
}

interface ICat extends IAnimal {
    meow: () => void;
}

function MyComponent({ pets }: { pets: (IDog | ICat)[] }) {
    // do something with pets

    return null;
}

function AnotherComponent() {
    const pets = [
        {
            bark: () => {},
            eat: () => {},
            name: 'Sparky',
        },
        {
            eat: () => {},
            meow: () => {},
            name: 'Whiskers',
        },
        {
            // TS2353: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bark' does not exist in type 'ICat'.
            // now you get a type error because of satisfies
            bark: () => {}, 
            eat: () => {},
            meow: () => {},
            name: 'Kitty',
        } satisfies ICat,
    ] satisfies (IDog | ICat)[];

    return <MyComponent pets={pets} />;
}
```